# Xamarin prism Dependency Service method cant get the variable on the current context in native

Tags: android, xamarin, prism

Can anyone help me with my problem? been trying to solve this for almost a week now. btw. Im using prism on xamarin.

Here is my code samples :

**Xamarin project**

*Interface*

```
public interface IVideoCommands
{
    void OnToggleVideo();
}
```

*ViewModel*

```
void OnToogleCommandVid()
{

    _dependencyService.Get<IVideoCommands>().OnToggleVideo();

}
```

**Android Project**

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(VideoService))]
namespace XTPProto.Droid.Services
{



    public class VideoService: Activity, IVideoCommands
    {

        private var libraryVariable _libVar;          

        private bool _isVideoEnabled;

        public bool IsVideoEnabled
        {
            get { return _isVideoEnabled; }
            set
            {
                if (_isVideoEnabled== value)
                    return;
                _isVideoEnabled= value;
                OnVideoChanged();

            }
        }

        private void init()
        {
          _libVar = new libraryVariable ();

        }

         protected void OnVideoChanged()
        {
            if (_libVar== null)
                return;
            if (_libVar.Function != IsVideoEnabled)
                _libVar.Function = IsVideoEnabled;
        }


        bool toggleVid = false;

        *Interface function

        void OnToggleVideo()
        {
            IsVideoEnabled = toggleVid = !toggleVid;

        }

    }

}
```

Every time I activate the interface function, all the variable in the android class is not initialized which means the interface is not apart of the context of the class (IMO) the variables within the class always return null on the method where interface was called.

Is there a proper way to make the interface function work with the current context of the android class?

I already tried the

```
 (_activity as Activity).RunOnUiThread(() => { IsVideoEnabled = vidToggle = !vidToggle; });
```

still not working :( anyone please help?

Comment: Have you tried preserving the class from being striped from the linker? Place [Android.Runtime.Preserve (AllMembers = true)] before public class VideoService:

Comment: Thank you for your response @hichame.yessou, I already tried it. still doesn't work :( maybe I'll try it to move all the method of the class to the interface.